# How to change Logitech ps/2 keyboard to usb one?

Tags: keyboard, logitech-keyboard, ps2-keyboard, usb-keyboard

I was using a cheap quantum(qhmpl) USB keyboard ,now it's keys not working so I thought to replace it with another keyboard . I have a working keyboard Logitech k100 but it's a ps/2 one .I searched about it and found that it's possible to change a ps/2 keyboard to a USB keyboard .so what I did is that I cut the usb socket and attached it to my Logitech ps/2 keyboard by replacing it's ps/2 socket with usb socket and linking same colour wires to each other . Now what I got is an unresponsive keyboard with all three lights blinking simultaneously . Can someone suggest me where is the exact problem and how should I resolve it . My pc doesn't have any problem and it has Intel dh87mc motherboard with usb sockets ONLY ,no ps/2 socket there ,thank you !

Note : It would be better if any Logitech user can suggest what different colour wires represent , for example kindly go through following vid to get an idea about it ,thank you!
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=V_ytY6lhzD0

Comment: You should have bought a PS/2 to USB convertor ...

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cable-Converter-Adaptor-Keyboard-Mouse/dp/B0012XGK3A

Comment: @DavidPostill I know that's a way but due to lockdown delivery is not possible at my location further I have seen this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=V_ytY6lhzD0 so what's your take ?

Answer (score -1):

The converters like these:

[image]

are just for the connections.

It will not make a USB-only keyboard work in PS/2.

It will not make a PS/2-only keyboard work on USB.

The keyboard that came with such an adapter was capable of both USB and PS/2 connections. It detects if it is plugged into a USB port or a PS/2 port and then adapts to that connection type.

Comment: The author's computer does not have any PS/2 ports.  The author is looking for a way to convert a PS/2 keyboard into a USB keyboard.  The product you suggest does not do that.

Comment: The photo is incorrect, OP needs a female PS/2 to male USB adapter. You're technically right, though: these adapters work only if hardware has explicitly designed support for them.

Comment: OP doesn't mention such an adapter.  It sounds like they tried to rewire a PS/2 keyboard to a USB port by hand.

Comment: @Ramhound upper answer is not recommending those devices rather it somewhere  accepting my point which I'm making that it doesn't matter even if I change its ps/2 adapter to a usb one ,what it needs that the usb connections of wire should be proper and in same line as previous ps/2 adapter so the answer is not all irrelevant though it doesn't solve my query !

Comment: @user716691 - This answer is extremely low quality.  It is not clear what the author actually intended.  Which is the reason it should be deleted.